# How can I visualize an XML file as a graph?

Tags: xml, graph, model, visualization, automaton

The following XML code represents a typestate model.

```
<graph id="tautoko/examples/MyProtocol" edgedefault="directed">
    <key id="key1" for="edge" attr.name="methodidentifiers" attr.type="string"/>
    <node id="node_1"/>
    <node id="node_0"/>
    <node id="node_2"/>
    <node id="node_3"/>
    <node id="start"/>
    <node id="ex"/>
    <edge id="e0" source="start" target="node_0">
        <data key="key1">tautoko/examples/MyProtocol.[init]()V#1</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e1" source="node_0" target="node_1">
        <data key="key1">tautoko/examples/MyProtocol.start()V#1</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e2" source="node_1" target="node_2">
        <data key="key1">tautoko/examples/MyProtocol.setSafeMode()V#1</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e3" source="node_2" target="node_3">
        <data key="key1">tautoko/examples/MyProtocol.drive()V#1</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e4" source="node_3" target="node_0">
        <data key="key1">tautoko/examples/MyProtocol.quit()V#1</data>
    </edge>
</graph>
```

Does anybody know a way (maybe a software) to visualize it?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Unfortunately your question will be closed soon because it is off-topic on SO.